# C# - Start new thread calling parameter method

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, methods

I'm working on one application which is using ASP.Net with C# in which I have one method with two parameters and I want to start it using `Thread`, to keep track either method execution is completed or not.

scenario:

Below is the method which I want to call in thread:

```
private long CreateAJobCopy(long jobID, long userID)
    {
        JobManagementClient jobManagementClient = new JobManagementClient();
        long newJobID=0;

        try
        {
            JobResultEntity jobResultEntity = jobManagementClient.CreateJobCopy(Common.AuthenticationToken, jobID, userID);
            if (jobResultEntity.Job != null)
                newJobID = jobResultEntity.Job.JobID;
            return newJobID;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex, Common.AuthenticationToken);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I want to display message to User that job is being created:

```
lblCreateJobCopyMessage.Text = "Please wait while new job is being created!";
```

when the method execution is completed I want to redirect to new page.

Comment: What technology are you working with here - ASP, Winforms, WPF, other?

Comment: Create `Started` and `Finished` events. Fire them when entering thread and leaving/terminating them.

Comment: @NicolasTyler: I have read that post but can't help. I have updated the question above.

Comment: I see the method returns a value, you're better off using a Task here as they can give you return values as-well as let you wait on the thread completion